# Waybar custom module in bash is not updating

Tags: bash

I've written a bash script to use within a [waybar](https://github.com/Alexays/Waybar) custom module. I'm trying to use it as an infinite loop but the custom module never updates.

My script (`volume.sh`) seems fine from the terminal. (for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Loop forever
while : ; do
    # Mangle the output of amixer into json
    amixer get Master | grep 'Mono:' |\
        sed -nre 's/.*\[off\].*/\{"text": "  M x ", "class": "muted", "percentage": 0\}/p; s/.*\[(.*)%\].*/\{"text": "\1% ", "class": "unmuted", "percentage": \1\}/p'

    # Wait until the next alsa event
    /usr/sbin/alsactl monitor | grep -m 0 .

    # Exit if alsactl monitor was interrupted
    if (( ${PIPESTATUS[0]} != 141 )); then
        break;
    fi
done
```

) and my waybar config is

```
"custom/alsa": {
    "exec": "~/.config/waybar/volume.sh",
    "return-type": "json",
    "on-click": "amixer set Master toggle",
    "on-scroll-up": "amixer set Master 5+",
    "on-scroll-down": "amixer set Master 5-",
    "tooltip": false
}
```

On launch of waybar the custom module displays correctly, but it never updates.

From a terminal `./volume.sh` outputs a line every time I change the volume or mute/unmute, which is what I want. The output from the terminal appears correct:

```
$ ./volume.sh
{"text": "43% ", "class": "unmuted", "percentage": 43}
{"text": "50% ", "class": "unmuted", "percentage": 50}
{"text": "  M x ", "class": "muted", "percentage": 0}
{"text": "57% ", "class": "unmuted", "percentage": 57}
```

(this would be after 4 events) which, I believe is a sensible output for waybar. As such I expect the issue is with what form the output should take (this will be specific to waybar, potentially) or how the module is configured.

If I remove the loop from `volume.sh` and put an interval into my custom module config then the module updates correctly, but I'm hoping to avoid polling.

Why is my custom waybar module not updating? Thanks!

## Appendix

For interest, the output of `amixer get Master` is

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 74
  Mono: Playback 49 [66%] [-25.00dB] [on]
```

but, again, the script's text output appears to be correct, and so the `amixer` line doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: What's waybar? Is it this: https://github.com/Alexays/Waybar? Something else? By the way, there is no need for `\ ` after `|`, you can end the line with the `|` just fine. Also, what is `volume.sh`? Is that the script you give at the beginning?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `amixer get Master | grep 'Mono:' ` on your system? Or,even better, of `amixer get Master`? On my system, `Mono:` is on a line by itself, so the `sed` command does nothing, it just blocks the output.

Comment: @terdon: yes, I've updated the Q with a link to be more specific. I didn't know that about line breaks - I'll leave it in, as it's easier to to be consistent rather than think ;). On my system Mono: is on a line with other details (including the volume and mute status). I'm not on a system with amixer at present so can't show you. As you can see in my last codeblock the output is as I'd expect and so the amixer/sed commands are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution and so can guess at reasons.

The working solution is

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

createJson(){
    amixer get Master |
        grep 'Mono:' |
        sed -nre 's/.*\[(.*)%\].*\[off\].*/\{"text": "\1% x", "class": "muted", "percentage": \1\}/p'\
            -e   's/.*\[(.*)%\].*/\{"text": "\1%  ", "class": "unmuted", "percentage": \1\}/p'
}

createJson
while read line; do
    createJson
done < <( /usr/sbin/alsactl monitor )
```

This reads one line at a time of the output from `alsactl`, pumping the relevant info from `amixer` each time (and ignoring the line from `alsactl`). I also tweaked the sed line so that you could still see the volume when it was muted, but that's just cosmetic.

I expect this works because the pipe containing the output of `alsactl` is never broken. In the original script `grep` terminates after each line, breaking the pipeline. Somehow this detatched `alsactl` (sending a `SIGCHLD` which showed up in the debug output from waybar) and knackered the script (but only in non-interactive mode). In the newer script `alsactl` just keeps piping to the while loop until we quit.